Sitecore 9.3.0 Marketing Automation Pool - Contact Removal?
I have a client running Sitecore 9.3.0 and their Marketing Automation process is running every 10 minutes and failing.
I've read the post about the long running CheckoutCommand stored procedure and how to decrease the time it takes to process and I've read the Marketing Automation documentation but can't find an answer to what seems like a simple question.
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1001377
After processing the contacts in the xdb_ma_pool.AutomationPool table, should the contact remain in that table? Or should it only be in that table until it is processes (which I think in this case means until it is added to one of the client's email campaigns as they don't have any Marketing Automation plans configurated and active).
